# How to use the value of an allocatable argument?

Tags: fortran, pack

I have the following code and I would like to save the value of idx to use afterwards.

```
program use_value_allocatable

  implicit none
  integer :: i, ii
  integer, dimension(3) :: array_save
  character(1), dimension(3) :: array_char_ref = (/'a','b','c'/), array_char_1 = (/'c','a','b'/)
  integer, allocatable :: idx(:)

  array_save = 0
  do i = 1, 3
     idx = pack([(ii,ii=1,3)], array_char_ref == array_char_1(i) )

     print*, 'i=', i, ', idx=', idx, ', array_save(i) =', array_save(i)
!!$     array_save(i) = idx
     deallocate(idx)
  end do

end program use_value_allocatable
```

Having array_save(i) = idx in the code leads to an error as follows:

```
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

So, I can conclude that I cannot use the value of an allocatable variable (here idx). How I can circumvent this problem?

P.S.: in this example I assume that idx will always be an integer of dimension 1

Comment: array_save(i) is a single variable (rank=0). array_save is an array (rank=1). In context, you presumably want to use the latter, not the former, in that assignment.

Comment: The allocatable attribute is irrelevant here. Also, you have no arguments. As lastchance pointed out, `idx` is an array, you cannot store an atray in one scalar element of `array_save(i)`.

Comment: Perhaps you could save idx into the whole array_save, if that is what you wanted to do. It is not completely clear to me. But you must also make sure, that the sizes if the arrays of both sides of the = assignment agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, "idx will always be an integer of dimension 1", so you just need

```
array_save(i) = idx(1)
```

i.e. you need to store the first (and only) element of `idx` in `array_save(i)`, rather than the whole array.

A side note: you do not need the line `deallocate(idx)`. `idx` will be implicitly re-allocated by the line `idx = ...`, and will be automatically deallocated when it drops out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer veryreverie. Just one question: we know that idx is an integer. So, we could have defined it as "integer :: idx" and then do "array_save(i) = idx". Why this is not working in our case?

Comment: I assume it isn't working on the line `idx = pack(...)`? This is because [`pack`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/PACK.html) returns "an array of rank one", not a scalar.